# Use desktop of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop with MobaXterm

Tags: vmware, xterm

i run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop in a VMware environment.

Is it possible to use the Gnome desktop with MobaXterm?

I tried things like sudo startx, which opens a new session in the remote console.

In the VMware Remote Console everything runs OK but i can't resize the screen to a bigger format.